# Overwrite default POM properties in command line

Tags: maven-3

Is it possible to directly overwrite attributes set in the POM?
I would like to change the packaging attribute:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  ...
</project>
```

So I try

```
mvn verify -Dproject.packaging=jar
```

like it is used to set parameters, but the packaging isn´t changed.

```
mvn verify -Dpackaging=jar
```

doesn´t work either.

Does this only work with properties defined on your own in `<properties>`?
What do I have to do to change the packaging temporarily?

Background: The project is a parent project and therefore uses `pom` as packaging. But it should also be possible to develop on the project itself and do testing etc., but with the packaging specified as `pom` maven doesn´t compile and test.

Comment: You can't change the packaging type by a property furthermore if the project is a parent it's should not have any sources etc. which needed to be compiled. That sounds like a separation of concerns problem in Maven.

Comment: @khmarbaise In my case the parent is kind of library for the children and should tested on itself, too...

Comment: Than your are using the parent in the wrong way.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using this like described here http://stdout.koraktor.de/blog/2011/04/15/using-a-git-submodule-as-maven-parent-project/